# Lightning Web Component - Not able to reference content asset file in LWC js

Tags: lightning-web-components

I uploaded an image in asset library and imported that using below code in my LWC js file

```
import PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE from '@salesforce/contentAssetUrl/placeholderImage'; 
export default class CpFeatures extends LightningElement {
    // Expose the asset file URL for use in the template
    placeholderImage = PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE;
}
```

When I am pushing the code to the org I am getting

> Exception while getting the content asset for reference
>   placeholderImage of type contentAssetUrl in file

Comment: This might be a simple question, but was the content asset uploaded to the same place you are deploying?

Comment: Yes, it was added to the same community's content assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.
To fix it I added the contentassets to my vscode project, and then the deployment went through.